# Select Statement - selecting first group of results where all entries are NOT Null

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a select statement that will allow me to select `the latest year in which every year Value contains an entry`

Taking the example below:

```
EarningsYearID EarningsID   Year   Value 
1                 1         2015    NULL
2                 1         2014    1.27
3                 1         2013    3.21
4                 2         2015    7.21
5                 2         2014    6.97
6                 2         2013    2.22
```

The correct answer should be '2014' as 2014 is the latest year in which all entries for that year, contain a NOT NULL value.

I tried with the following query:

```
DECLARE @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies as int;

SET @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies = (SELECT TOP 1 ey.[Year]
    FROM company c, earnings e, earningsYear ey
    WHERE c.ticker_id = e.ticker_id
    AND e.EarningsID = ey.EarningsID
    AND c.tickerSymbol IN ('AA', 'BB')
    AND ey.Value is not null ORDER by ey.[Year] DESC);
```

However, this returns '2015' which is incorrect as there exists a '2015' entry that is NULL, i require all entries to be NOT NULL. Therefore the next available year 2014 should be the correct answer.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is lacking an order by column, you can try the code below:

```
SET @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies = (SELECT TOP 1 ey.[Year]
    FROM company c, earnings e, earningsYear ey
    WHERE c.ticker_id = e.ticker_id
    AND e.EarningsID = ey.EarningsID
    AND c.tickerSymbol IN ('AA', 'BB')
    AND ey.Value is not null ORDER by ey.EarningsID, ey.[Year] DESC);
```

You can also refer below for readability:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies = ey.[Year]
FROM
    company c
    JOIN earnings e ON c.ticker_id = e.ticker_id
    JOIN earningsYear ey ON e.EarningsID = ey.EarningsID
WHERE
    c.tickerSymbol IN ('AA', 'BB')
    AND ey.Value is not null
ORDER by
    ey.EarningsID, 
    ey.[Year] DESC
```

Please refer below for the updated script:

```
; WITH YEARVALUE ([Year], Value)
AS
(
    SELECT
        ey.[Year], ey.Value
    FROM
        company c
        JOIN earnings e ON c.ticker_id = e.ticker_id
        JOIN earningsYear ey ON e.EarningsID = ey.EarningsID
    WHERE
        c.tickerSymbol IN ('AA', 'BB')
)

SELECT
    @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies = MAX(Year)
FROM
    YEARVALUE
WHERE
    [Year] NOT IN (
        SELECT
            Year
        FROM
            YEARVALUE
        WHERE
            Value IS NULL)

SELECT @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies --show latest year with no null value
```

Answer (score 0):

if value is positive

```
select max([Year]) 
from 
(
SELECT [Year]
FROM company c, earnings e, earningsYear ey
WHERE c.ticker_id = e.ticker_id
AND e.EarningsID = ey.EarningsID
AND c.tickerSymbol IN ('AA', 'BB') 
group by [Year]
having min(isnull(ey.Value, -1000)) > -1000 
) tt
```

Comment: Sorry, actually 'Value' maybe negative in some cases

Comment: is there a minimum value it will never go below you could use?

Comment: unfortunately not, i mean i could use some absurd figure but it would be a kind of hack which im not to keen on.

Comment: Hack?  Absurd?  For the datatype there will be minimum.

Comment: if i use a large negative value i.e > -1000 then it's returning multiple years

Comment: Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Comment: Makes no sense to me if it was returning multiple rows before.  I will leave it up a day and then delete.   Did you like try casting to numeric?

Comment: Yes, tried casting, i will play around with it and see how far i can get, appreciate your input, thanks.